# Jekyll: Liquid custom output statement for dynamic CSS classes

Tags: html, css, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

My Jekyll website has two kinds of content: **personal**, and **professional**.

I would like to emphasize which kind of content a visitor is currently reading with dynamic CSS classes:

- If the visitor is on a page tagged as "personal", my `<main>` element's class should be `"personal-content"`.
- If the visitor is on a page tagged as "professional", my `<main>` element's class should be `"professional-content"`.
- Otherwise, the class should be `"site-content"`.

In the front-matter of each page, I'm creating an output statement that I set either at `"personal"` or `"professional"`, for example:

```
---
content: "personal"
----
```

Then I'm using this output statement in my  tag like this: (indented for reading purposes)

```
<main
{% if page.content %}
    class="{{ page.content }}-content"
    {% else %}
        class="site-content"
{% endif %}
>
```

However I'm only seeing styling from my `site-content` class. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does the other class (personal-content or professional-content) appear in the HTML output?

Comment: `{{ page.content | inspect }}` can give you a clue on what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @APerson, I looked at the generated HTML and found that this is my opening <main> tag: `<main  class="`. Not only the custom class setting doesn't work, but it also makes my page invalid html.

Comment: @DavidJacquel thanks to this I think I figured it out: Jekyll is already using "content" to include markdown articles into layouts! {{ page.content | inspect }} actually returned my page's copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, I fixed it!

The problem was that I was not using a custom output statement as I thought I was: **`{{ content }}` is already used by Jekyll** to include markdown articles into HTML layouts.

So I switched `{{ page.content }}` to `{{ page.contenttype }}` and it works fine!

**Caveat:**
I also had to change the values I was giving my output statement. `professional` was working fine, but for some reason `personal` was returning `nil`. So I simply switched them for `pro` and `perso` and voilà.